# How can I cancel event tracking for mobile websites (server-side) for Crawler Bots?

Tags: php, mobile, google-analytics, server-side

At the moment I'm using server-side implementation of Google Analytics for Mobile websites. You know, there's used an image for sending tracking data. Is it possible not to track events when bots are crawling mobile websites?

Maybe I should use rel="nofollow" property for  tag?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a robots.txt file or comparable robots blocking mechanisms (http://www.robotstxt.org/ for examples), but this is only if you don't want your content scraped by bots for search engine purposes.

I haven't used the server-side Google analytics, but if they are the same as the Google-hosted service, but I think Google does a rather decent job at blocking bots (http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1315708) and allows you to identify and block bots from your reports (http://www.blastam.com/blog/index.php/2012/06/block-web-monitoring-bots-in-google-analytics/).

Answer (score 0):

These bots don't understand frames, Flash movies, images or JavaScript. They can't click any buttons on a website, if there isnt a static link for them to follow, they wont follow it.  Event tracking in GA is javascript based and requires action on the users part so there should be no bot traffic showing up in your GA events report.